# How do I increase "ulimit -u" (max user processes)?

Tags: macos, launchd, kernel

I can change all of the usual ulimits via (for instance) `ulimit -n 8192` and `launchctl limit maxfiles 8192 8192`. Somehow, this doesn't seem to work for `-u`, the maximum number of user processes:

```
~$ sudo launchctl limit maxproc 8192 8192
~$ sudo launchctl limit maxproc
    maxproc     2048           2048
-- in a new terminal:
~$ ulimit -u
1064
```

I do get a "failed to fork" every once in a while, and it's quite annoying having to kill a bunch of processes when "kill" can't start :) (i.e. I usually resort to just rebooting the machine).

What's the correct way to change the maximum number of user processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/ talks about this issue in great detail.

When you do `sudo launchctl limit maxproc`, you're viewing or changing the system-wide launchd limits.

When you do `launchctl limit maxproc`, you're viewing or changing the launchd limits for your user.

One thing to keep in mind is this:

> The root user can increase the hard limits of the system-wide launchd,
>   without a reboot.  However, you cannot change a user’s launchd hard
>   limits without a reboot (even if trying to do so as the root user).

Basically, the hard limit (the right hand column) that is displayed when you initially do `launchctl limit maxproc` will be the limit that you can set using `ulimit -u` without rebooting.  Logging out and back in will not work.  Even if you change whats displayed by `launchctl limit maxproc`, the initial hard limit remains.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116754/80135) for a bit more info on the relationship between `ulimit` and `launchctl limit`.
To raise that limit, you have to

- edit/create `/etc/sysctl.conf` to raise the maximum processes supported by the kernel

  ```
  kern.maxproc=2500
  kern.maxprocperuid=2500
  ```
- edit/create `/etc/launchd.conf` to raise the hard limits of the system-wide launchd at boot time

  ```
  limit maxproc 2500 2500
  ```
- reboot

Also note that 2500 seems to be the maximum limit that `kern.maxproc` can be set to.  I'll ask a question about this as soon as I reboot and have enough free processes to open another Chrome tab.

Comment: Note: The `launchd.conf` method [no longer works in Mavericks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108174/21471) and other newer distributions.